# Discount UML diagram

Tags: database, uml

I would like to know how to do this in my DataBase. So I tried to do an UML digram.

But I still not succeed to do that. I don't have to do a UML diagram. It's just I don't know how to do this situation in a Data base.

My situation :

I would like to manage discount on my website.
The discount are like that :
You have a discount with :

1. begin and
2. end date

You can have a porcentage discount or aboslute discount 
(example -20% or -10€).

Discount are made on :

1. Product (one to many) (only specific product, ex: product_id:21)
2. order (one to many) (on the full order, so the total of all products, ex order_id:33)
3. product with specific provider (one to many) ( ex provider_id: 12)
4. only for one or X customer (one to many) (ex : customer_id:12 and customer_id:24)

[image]

The problem is : I have 3 table with the same "midle table" with pretty much the same attributes... i don't know how to simplify that...

Comment: Ok :) I did that

Comment: You should not start with a DB design but rather a class diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options, each has some benefits and drawbacks. The way you've designed it is definitely one of possible approaches. The benefit is that you fully utilise native DB technologies (especially FK). The drawback is that you end up with a complex design.

Other option that comes to my mind is that you may build just one joining table `in_promotion` with three attributes:

```
+fk_id_promotion : integer
+fk_id_prmotionRecipient : string
+promotionRecipientType
```

The second is actually not a true FK in the DB understanding. On th other hand the last one would probably be also a FK to some dictionary but I'll skip that for a moment.

In this approach you mix FKs to different tables, depending on the type indicated in promotionRecipientType. Rather than four tables you have one.

The benefit of such approach is that you have easier to follow model (to a degree!) but you end up with a solution which is less efficient (you can't simply jon tables, you need to read those information separately and merge them on the application level. Other significant drawback is that it limits your choices of PK types - they have to be the same in all tables for objects that are subject to a promotion.

You may also mix different approaches or solve the drawbacks mentioned earlier in other ways (causing further different drawbacks). Options are virtually endless and it's impossible to list all of them.

Over time you'll learn recognising which way works best in a specific case.

Comment: Thank you :) I did both solution today. And I will try the second one. Because my DB is already huge and I want to reduce the number of needed table. [img_new_UML](https://imgur.com/a/8WDwAPs)